# Use pipenv with django heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pipenv

So I began to code a project with python, and I was using a tutorial that told me to use a pip environment as my virtual environment. A problem arose, however, when I performed the `git push heroku master` command. It could not find the package `django-heroku`!

I was confused, because when I ran `python manage.py runserver`, the server on my computer ran. I then changed to a python environment, which was located in the directory I was pushing to heroku. The problem was solved! The virtual environment, and consequently the installed packages, were inside the directory being pushed to git, and I could use them in my website!

But the question still remains: can you use a pip environment for a django project being pushed to git? Thanks!

Comment: Git is not in fact involved in any of this. Git is just storing stuff for you and transferring stored stuff from computer A to computer B, and none of this depends on virtual environments. Venvs change the way *Python* behaves (by changing the `sys.path`).

Comment: You mention Pipenv in your title and you tagged this with the [tag:pipenv] tag, but nowhere in your question do you say anything about Pipenv, mention a `Pipfile`, etc. Your question appears to be purely about pip. Which are you using?

Comment: pip environment is the same as `pipenv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include python packages within your repo and push them to Heroku. Check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip. You only need a requirements.txt file in your root directory. Heroku will install the packages automatically for you.